# Write Python code that reads the line contents of a text file and return index of words into numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code in python that goes through a text file and creates a word index of every word in the file. However, It's not executing properly. So far this is what I have:

```
import sys
import re
                                                                                                                               
line = sys.stdin.readline()                                                                                                    
pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
while line:
    def build_word_index(txt):
        out = {}                                                                                                               
        for i, line in enumerate(txt.split("\n")):
            for word in line.strip().split(" "):
                if word not in out:
                    out[word] = [i + 1]
                else:
                    out[word].append(i + 1)
        return out
```

Comment: What in particular isn't working? Syntax errors? Incorrect output?

Comment: It basically just keeps running without any outputs and doesn't end until I terminate it.

Comment: You never call build_word_index?

Comment: You've got an infinite `while` loop that defines a function that's never called, and nothing else, so the loop can never end.

Comment: Generally speaking you almost never need/want to define functions *inside* loops.

Comment: Also, why are you using `sys.stdin.readline()` and not the built-in `input()`?

Comment: @ddejohn I'm using python in Hadoop to input text files into my code

Answer (score 0):

You never call the function!

```py
import sys
import re
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")

def build_word_index(txt):
        out = {}                                                                                                               
        for i, line in enumerate(txt.split("\n")):
            for word in line.strip().split(" "):
                if word not in out:
                    out[word] = [i + 1]
                else:
                    out[word].append(i + 1)
        return out

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    out = build_word_index(line)
    print(out)
```

Comment: I get an invalid syntax at this line "while line := sys.stdin.readline():", could i use an if statement since I'm using python 3.6

Comment: As the latest Python Version is 3.10, you'd better use 3.8 or 3.9. Python3.6 is not the recomment one.